# What is the difference between running "python" and "python2.7" on a Mac OS X?

Tags: python, macos

When I run `python` from a terminal on my Mac, I get the following first two lines back:

```
Python 2.7.5 (v2.7.5:ab05e7dd2788, May 13 2013, 13:18:45)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
```

When I run `python2.7`, I get this:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 19 2013, 13:26:46)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
```

I can recognize `scipy` and `numpy` in python2.7, but not in plain python.

What precisely is the difference between these? Is there any way I can make python `import scipy`? Can I just alias python2.7 to python and forget about this?

Answer (score 4):

Those are two different `python`s.

Try `whereis python` and `whereis python2.7` to get their specific locations.

Answer (score 3):

On a Mac (at lesat with OS X 10.7.0 through the latest 10.8.x), the pre-installed Python at `/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/bin/python2.7` is Apple's 2.7.2 build.

If you have two different 2.7.5 builds, you must have installed them manually. And nobody but you can possibly know how you did that.

The `which` command may help. For example, you may find that the first `python` on your PATH is a `/usr/local/bin/python` which is a symlink to `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/bin/python`, while the first `python2.7` on your PATH is `/opt/local/bin/python2.7`, which is an executable. That would mean that you installed a Homebrew Python 2.7.5, and you also installed a MacPorts Python 2.7.5, and you did the latter in such a way that it didn't create a `python` symlink, and you've got MacPorts higher on your PATH than Homebrew.

But whatever you've done, it scarcely matters. If you don't understand how to manage this stuff yourself, the best thing to do is to uninstall all of the extra Pythons you installed and just use a single Python 2.7. That means you will need to reinstall any modules, of course, but it's worth doing.

I know some people believe that it's worth getting *one* additional Python 2.7 installation and using that in place of Apple's, but nobody is going to tell you to get two additional Python 2.7 installations and use both of them.

Answer (score 0):

`man python` on the mac will tell you "To support multiple versions, the programs named python and pythonw now just select the real version of Python to run, depending on various settings."

When you call 'python2.7' you are selecting the version, while the 'python' chooses a version based on what is available and environment variables like VERSIONER_PYTHON_VERSION=2.7